# Django runserver error, new installation, first time user of Django

Tags: python, django, linux, conda

So I've decided to learn Django, which will be challenging if I cannot get it working.

Running
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

(base) runout@runout:~$ python -m django --version
2.2.1

I'm following the tutorial for beginners at [djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)

The first line of code was to create a site, which i did...

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

The second line of code, is where I run into problems.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

My error is as follows:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip
  File "/home/runout/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/introspection.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse'
```

I know nothing of Django, I'm excited to learn. I've looked all over the net and SO for a solution to this problem to no avail. Can anyone get me up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a python package is missing. You can install it like this:

`pip install sqlparse`

Answer (score 1):

You're on Linux so install 'sqlparse' by typing:
`pip3 install sqlparse`. Also you should call python with `python3`, so that it's not confused with python2.